# file() returning null when file content have words with "accent"

Tags: php

Here's the code:

```
$content = file($_FILES['tmp_name']); // This is a TXT file uploaded
echo json_encode($content);
```

When the `tmp_name` file content is `cancao` I got `["cancao"]` but if the `tmp_name` file content is `canção` I got `null`.

Comment: You need to look at the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and learn how to use the upload process properly see specifically `move_uploaded_file()` and the error checking code as well

Comment: I don't need `move_uploaded_file()` since I just need the content of the file and the code that I provided at question is doing this. About `check error code` I already know the issue is about the file content with words with accent like I said at question too.

Comment: Can you give a clue as to what the contents of `$content` is

Comment: like I said at question if the file content is `cancao` so  `$content` is `[cancao]` but if the file content is `canção` so the `$content` is returning `null`

Comment: You dont normally `json_encode()` a single text string. What is in the file and therefore in `$content` Give us a bit of a clue it does not have to be actual data, just an accurate representation

Comment: I've had this issue before. Try doing: `echo json_encode(utf8_encode($content));`. This worked for me.